# Odoo: trigger on_change when updating records on a one2many field?

Tags: python, odoo

How to trigger on_change when updating records on a one2many field?

Answer (score 2):

```
    .. warning::

        ``@onchange`` only supports simple field names, dotted names
        (fields of relational fields e.g. ``partner_id.tz``) are not
        supported and will be ignored

    .. danger::

        Since ``@onchange`` returns a recordset of pseudo-records,
        calling any one of the CRUD methods
        (:meth:`create`, :meth:`read`, :meth:`write`, :meth:`unlink`)
        on the aforementioned recordset is undefined behaviour,
        as they potentially do not exist in the database yet.

        Instead, simply set the record's field like shown in the example
        above or call the :meth:`update` method.

    .. warning::

        It is not possible for a ``one2many`` or ``many2many`` field to modify
        itself via onchange. This is a webclient limitation - see `#2693 <https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2693>`_.
```

This is what I got when I see the code of @api.onchange, it just not support one2many

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.
Just follow the below steps:

1. Create a Many2one field.
2. Create a One2many field for storing onchange records.
3. Create onchange method.

**Code:**

```
many2one_field = fields.Many2one('One2manyFieldModelName', string="Many2one Field")

one2many_record_field = fields.One2many('Many2oneFieldModelName', 'field_name', store=True)

@api.onchange('many2one_field')
def _onchange_many2one_field(self):
    self.one2many_record_field = self.env['One2manyFieldModelName'].search([('One2manyFieldName', '=', self.many2one_field)])
```

And Also if you are using Odoo Version 11 and above then you have to give attribute force_save in XML to save the read-only fields in onchange.

```
<field name="field_name" force_save="1"/>
```

**Explanation:**
Created one Many2one field that contains one2many field data, then created one one2many field that store onchange records as you want, then after just called onchange method and store records using the search function, you can use any functions like search, browse, etc.

I hope it's understandable for you, if not just comment.

Accept the answer if useful...

Thank you :)

Comment: thanks for proposing solution
I looked closely, but maybe my question is not so clear, 
I have modelA and modelB.
a one2many_field-modelA linked to the many2one_field-modelB
What I need is to trigger on_change, if I edit any of the fields on already created record in one2many_field-modelA.
I could set an on_change for the whole modelB, but I was thinking if there was a better/cleaner solution

Comment: @Koul In your case, it might be cleaner to just override the write method in model A.